How do I change this Summon command to work with 1.20.5?
I need help with changing a summon command to work in 1.20.5. The command appears to be correct, however, when I summon the mob it has armor/weapons but the enchantments don't work.
The command is:
/summon zombified_piglin ~1 ~ ~-2 {CustomName:"\"Bank Guard \"",Team:Blue, Tags:[BAUnit1_B],PersistenceRequired:1,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:golden_sword,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:sweeping_edge,lvl:4},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]}},{}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:golden_boots,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1}]}},{Count:1,id:golden_leggings,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1}]}},{Count:1,id:golden_chestplate,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1}]}},{Count:1,id:golden_helmet,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1}]}}],IsImmuneToZombification:1b}

Also can you please explain how it works so that I can apply to all my other summon commands I use in my map I am creating? I don't need an example of necessarily every attribute in this command just anything that may differ in how it is typed.

Hey thanks for the reply unfortunately it did not work for me. I tried both of those options in front of a /summon zombie ~ ~ ~ command and it didn't work. command used: /summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Count:1,id:golden_sword,components:{"minecraft:enchantments":["minecraft:sweeping_edge":4,"minecraft:unbreaking":3]}}

In 1.20.5, NBT tags (the tag element) in items have been replaced with components. You will need to convert your command.
For example, the sword your entity carries:
{Count:1,id:golden_sword,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:sweeping_edge,lvl:4},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]}}

Would become:
{Count:1,id:golden_sword,components:{"minecraft:enchantments":["minecraft:sweeping_edge":4,"minecraft:unbreaking":3]}}

or
{Count:1,id:golden_sword,components:{"minecraft:enchantments":{"levels":["minecraft:sweeping_edge":4,"minecraft:unbreaking":3],"show_in_tooltip":true}}}

You can read more about it on the Minecraft Wiki.
